# Joining four tables with left or right join

Tags: mysql

I have four tables.

1. Level Table **levels**(id, name)
2. Student Table **students**(id, name, level_id)
3. Subject Table **subjects**(id, name)
4. Report Table **reports**(id, student_id, subject_id, test, exam)

I need a single query that will fetch results(report table) for a single level(e.g **id=1** for *Class One*) and a particular subject(e.g **id=2** for like *English*)

I have this query:

```
select name, test, exam 
from `reports` 
right join `students` 
on `reports`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
where `students`.`level_id` = '1' 
and `reports`.`subject_id` = '2'
```

But it's only showing result for records that are inside the reports table. Am expecting all data from the students table where the level_id is specified but with NULL from their **test** and **exam** row if they don't have record in the results table.

The main issue is the subject_id clause(**and `reports`.`subject_id` = '2'**) on the query. It's only working for record if present in the records table [Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yExO2.png)

When I used subject_id that's not in the result table [Here is the result -not returning anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjARz.png)

Comment: "inside the reports table"...you don't mention a reports table initially. Did you mean "results"? Or is this another table you didn't list?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and note that nobody ever actually uses RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: @Adyson... sorry for misleading you. Am mistakingly using result table instead of report table... I've corrected it

Answer (score 1):

> But it's only showing result for records that are inside the reports table

Not strictly true - its only showing results where `reports.subject_id = '2'`. If there is no matching row in the reports table, then the subject_id would be null, and null is not equal to 2.

You need to specify the predicate for the reports table in the join clause, not in the where clause, to get all the students:

```
 select name, test, exam 
 from `reports` 
 right join `students` 
 on `reports`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
 and `reports`.`subject_id` = '2'
 where `students`.`level_id` = '1'
```

Comment: I now understand the difference between the **where** clause and the clause on the **Join On** clause... Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can try below statement to get all student with level=1

```
select name
     , test
     , exam 
  from students 
  join reports 
    on  students.id = reports.student_id 
   and reports.subject_id = 2 
 where students.level_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. But I think **left join** will be suited for my use case...